Airflow Docker - ModuleNotFoundError with python scripts
I have been facing some error since yesterday when trying to run my airflow project using docker.I keep getting the ModuleNotFoundError when the code gets to import functions from files at 'scripts' directory.

Broken DAG: [/opt/airflow/dags/transport_etl_dag.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/opt/airflow/dags/transport_etl_dag.py", line 7, in 
from scripts.utensils import get_snowpark_session
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scripts'

My project tree is:
root  
dags:
  transport_etl_dag.py
  transport_etl_tasks.py  
scripts:
  __init__.py
  utensils.py  
dockerfile  
docker-compose  
docker-entrypoint  
requirements.txt  

I have tried all possible ways to solve this, that i could possibly find here. Specifying the PYTHONPATH, etc. Here is how my dockerfile and docker-compose look.
dockerfile:
FROM python:3.8

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y\
    build-essential \
    curl \
    libpq-dev \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV AIRFLOW_HOME=/opt/airflow
ENV PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/opt/airflow/scripts

RUN pip install apache-airflow==2.2.2

COPY dags/ $AIRFLOW_HOME/dags/
COPY config/ $AIRFLOW_HOME/config/
COPY scripts/ $AIRFLOW_HOME/scripts/

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh

RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

CMD ["webserver"]

docker compose:
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  webserver:
    image: my_transport_image
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: LocalExecutor
      AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
      AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'false'
      AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'false'
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    command: webserver
    volumes:
      - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
      - ./config:/opt/airflow/config
      - ./scripts:/opt/airflow/scripts

  scheduler:
    image: my_transport_image
    depends_on:
      - webserver
    environment:
      AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: LocalExecutor
      AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
      AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'false'
    command: scheduler
    volumes:
      - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
      - ./config:/opt/airflow/config
      - ./scripts:/opt/airflow/scripts

volumes:
  postgres_data:

when in scheduler's terminal at docker, echo $PYTHONPATH  gives me :/opt/airflow/scripts
# ls /opt/airflow
airflow.cfg  config  dags  logs  scripts  webserver_config.py
# ls /opt/airflow/dags
__init__.py  __pycache__  transport_etl_dag.py  transport_etl_tasks.py
# ls opt/airflow/scripts
__init__.py  consumption.py  curated.py  raw.py  utensils.py

The dag file imports and setup:
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.sensors.filesystem import FileSensor
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import json
import os
from scripts.utensils import get_snowpark_session

# Import the combined task functions
from transport_etl_tasks import (
    few functions
)
from scripts.curated import (
    few functions
)
from scripts.consumption import (
    few functions
)

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'email': ['email@example.com'],
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

dag = DAG(
    'transport_data_etl',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='ETL for transport data',
    schedule_interval='@daily',
    start_date=datetime(2024, 1, 1),
    catchup=False,
)

so everything should theoretically work... Would appreciate Your help, thanks in advance!!!

Could you share the dag also please

Sure, just added to the post!

I think you just need to tweak your definition of PYTHONPATH in your Dockerfile.
At present you have this:
ENV PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/opt/airflow/scripts

This means that from scripts.utensils import get_snowpark_session will look in /opt/airflow/scripts/scripts (where the scripts at the end has been duplicated).
If you change to
ENV PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:${AIRFLOW_HOME}

then Python will start looking for files below /opt/airflow/ and will find scripts/utensils.py at /opt/airflow/scripts/utensils.py
